# How to mark mails as read using ImapX lib? C#

Tags: c#, message, imapx

I'm using the free lib ImapX and I'm making an application  to mark all my mails as receieved. Can anyone lend me a hand?

EDIT: Nevermind, found it out myself. They get marked as read when you process them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add flag, which will help you to update status as seen.

```
  foreach (var mess in messages)
  {
   mess.SEEN = true; 
  }
```

Let me know if you are unable to change status.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you're using the old ImapX library, I invite you to upgrade to [ImapX 2](http://imapx.codeplex.com/). It's being constantly developed and supported. There is also sample code for all common operations.

The `Process` method of a message doesn't mark the message as read, it only downloads the whole message including attachments. In your case, if you call the `Search` method setting the second parameter to `true`, you don't have to call it for every single message.

To mark a message as read simply use the `AddFlag` method of Message:

```
ImapX.FolderCollection folders = imapclient.Folders;
ImapX.MessageCollection messages = imapclient.Folders["INBOX"].Search("UNSEEN", true); 
foreach (var mess in messages)
{
    mess.AddFlag(ImapFlags.SEEN); 
}
```